# iOS example that records strokes on screen as vector input

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm looking for an iOS app or example code that allows a user to draw on the screen and records the drawing as some sort of vector format.  What I have in mind is similar to this app:

http://mugtug.com/sketchpad/

Except much simpler-- the example or app doesn't necessarily need to support brushes or colors, just save the user's strokes in some vector format (i.e. a sequence of (x, y) points for each stroke).

Apps like SketchBook MobileX supports basic drawing functionality, but as far as I can tell it only saves sketches as images:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sketchbook-mobilex/id327376639?mt=8

Does anything like this exist yet?

Thanks!!

Comment: I just found a free app that does what I need. neu.Notes for the iPad will email PDFs of sketches, and the PDFs contain vector data:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/neu-notes/id373693319?mt=8

A code example would be awesome, but this app fulfills the main goal of being able to record sketches as vector data.

Comment: You might want to check out TouchDraw, it supports the most vector based formats I have seen in an iPad app http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/touchdraw/id382021233?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Example and Library with Smooth line View: https://github.com/interlock/Smooth-Line-View

It records points and renders as Splines or Bezier curves. Could easily be modified to output SVG. If you do, send a pull request and I'll integrate it :-)